# How can I make my computer display on my monitor?

Tags: display, hardware-failure

Last night, I cleaned the dust inside of my tower with "Dust-Off Electronics compressed-gas Duster". Now when I plug in the tower to my monitor, nothing displays. This started right after I cleaned the tower. If I press space and enter my password and run cmd and run "echo ^G" (without quotes and ^G = ctrl+g), I do hear a noise. I couldn't see what was happening, I just did this from memory. I also tried replacing the HDMI cable, and that didn't help. I also took out the ram and put it back in, which didn't help. Lastly, I also tried unplugging everything after powering it off and plugging everything back in. Any idea how to fix this? Here are my system specs:

OS: Windows 10

CPU cooler: Thermaltake

GPU: Geforce GTX gigabyte

Battery: AX-500 XT

SSD: Gamer King 1TB SSD and teamgroup GX2 SSD

Motherboard: Gigabyte GA-A320M-S2H

If there is anything else I can do to improve this post, please let me know and I will do so.

Comment: If you can't find where the problem is, you'll need a repair-shop.

Comment: So.. when you say "Geforce GTX gigabyte", do you mean the onboard video?  This can mean many things since gigabyte makes both cards and motherboards.   If not, have you tried removing the video and running directly off of the onboard for troubleshooting?  Also, pull everything, blow again, re-seat everything.  Blowing out your case is probably not your problem other than "something" needs to be reseated.. happens all of the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your monitor has multiple inputs, be sure that its on the **correct input.** Some of the monitors doesn’t auto switch to the correct input and had to be manually switched.

*I’m considering that you’ve already tested these monitors on other computers to make sure they’re working well.*

Does the computer beep when you start it? Another problem that causes no display is **memory or CPU** **not begin installed correctly.**

Lastly your monitor should be plugged into your **graphics card** and **not the HDMI port** on your motherboard.

If all of them didn’t work please let me know.

Comment: Heh.. nice guess sir.  I didn't even think of that. :)

Comment: Yeah, I forgot that there were two HDMI ports. I plugged the plugin into the port on the motherboard, but then I put it in the one in the graphics card, and that did the trick.